# Print only one result using for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am checking if each character within a string is alphanumeric and alphabetical. If all the characters within a string is alphanumeric/ alphabetical, I would print 'True', otherwise would print 'False'. My code is as below.

```
s = 'a2'
for i in s:
    if i.isalnum():
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')

    if i.isalpha():
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

However, since I am using a For loop based on character within string, it would print out 4 results.

```
>>> Current output
True
True
True
False
```

But I want to print out result based on each string as a whole, so there should be only 2 results. Can anyone offer a help? Many thanks!!

```
>>>Expected output
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do both functions isalnum() and isalpha() for the entire string

```
print(s.isalnum())
print(s.isaplha())
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is combine your two `if` statements using the `and` operator, and you will get your expected output:

```
s = 'a2'
for i in s:
    if i.isalnum() and i.isalpha():
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

The preceding script produces the following output:

```
True
False
```